# Writing my own WPF framework for a chat program - how do I keep the window open?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I don't want to directly run the form when I start the program and dont want all the execution of code inside the forms constructor:

```
network
threading
computation
```

Inside:

```
LoginWindows() { /* Constructor */ }
```

So I switched the entry into a Main function from LoginWindow.xaml but when I classify it as a STAThread and run the LoginWindow and some other threads from the main function the login window closes for some reason but the threading continues normally and the program doesnt quit. Pic related below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3gVo.png

Comment: As a side note, "writing my own WPF framework" is not what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

put your initialization logic in the `override OnStartup()` method in the app.xaml.cs file. You may also want to provide some kind of splash screen if it takes too much for your code to complete.